# PAM - required and sufficient control flag

Tags: authentication, pam

I'm studying PAM, and I'm a bit clueless about the meaning of some combination of control flags. From the Red Hat documentation we have:

> - required
>     failure of such a PAM will ultimately lead to the PAM-API returning failure
>     but only after the remaining stacked modules (for this service and type)
>     have been invoked
> - requisite
>     like required, however, in the case that such a module returns a failure,
>     control is directly returned to the application.
> - sufficient
>     success of such a module is enough to satisfy the authentication
>     requirements of the stack of modules (if a prior required module has failed
>     the success of this one is ignored). A failure of this module is not deemed
>     as fatal to satisfying the application that this type has succeeded. If the
>     module succeeds the PAM framework returns success to the application
>     immediately without trying any other modules.

So, in my understanding, if a module `requisite` fails, the entire stack of modules will not be parsed, and the control will be back to the application immediately.
If a module `sufficient` succeeds, the rest of modules stack will not be parsed and the control will be back to the application immediately.
If a module `required` fails, the entire stack will be parsed.

Now, I cannot understand what will be the behavior when a certain module `required` fails and another module `sufficient` succeeds.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

PAM proceeds through the items on the stack in sequence. It only keeps the memory of what state it's in (success or denied, with success meaning success so far), not of how it reached that state.

If an item marked `sufficient` succeeds, the PAM library stops processing that stack. This happens whether there were previous `required` items or not. At this point, PAM returns the current state: success if no previous `required` item failed, otherwise denied.

Similarly, if an item marked `requisite` fails, the PAM library stops processing and returns a failure. At that point, it's irrelevant whether a previous `required` item failed.

In other words, `required` doesn't necessarily cause the whole stack to be processed. It only means to keep going.

Comment: But if any `required` item failed, why does `PAM` need to keep going through the stack? if it will finally fail anyway?

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin Even if a login attempt fails, some things must be done, such as logging, adding a timeout against brute-force attempts, etc. Also usually the system doesn't reveal the exact reason for the failure, e.g. if looking up the username fails then the user is still prompted for a password.

Comment: The order is the order in which they are listed in the config?

Comment: @OrangeDog Yes. The module listed on the first line is executed, then the second line is executed (or skipped depending on the result of the first line), etc.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, a `required` control flag has to be always successful in order for a module to be successful.

A `sufficient` flagged module is ignored if it fails. If it is successful and no `required` flagged modules above have failed then, no other modules of the same type  have to be checked and the module is considered successful. So basically, the `required` flag has higher priority than the `sufficient` flag but the latter one has ability to stop checking the rest of them if the previous `required` ones succeeded.

Example:

```
1 auth       required     /lib/security/pam_nologin.so
2 auth       required     /lib/security/pam_securetty.so
3 auth       required     /lib/security/pam_env.so
4 auth       sufficient   /lib/security/pam_rhosts_auth.so
5 auth       required     /lib/security/pam_stack.so service=system-auth
```

If lines 1, 2, 3 and 4 are successful then, the line 5 can be skipped and the module `auth` is successful. If the line 4 is not successful it is ignored and the line 5 is checked. If any of the lines 1, 2, 3 has failed then, the line 4 is not taken into account.

Comment: I think his question is what happens if 1 fails and 2-4 succeed.  Does 5 get run?  If 1 had succeeded, 5 would not be run.  Or in other words, does the "stop after sufficient succeeds" apply if a previous required module failed?

Comment: No, the auth module would fail with such combination.

Comment: The question isn't whether the authorization will fail.  It will.  The question is whether module 5 will run before that failure is reported to the application.